# incorrect transaction count

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, web3j, infura

I am trying to find the transaction count of an address using ethGetTransactionCount method but it's returning 0 value. What the issue over here. I'm using infura mainnet and web3j in maven

```
/Find the current transaction count/
EthGetTransactionCount txnCount = web3j.ethGetTransactionCount("0xa9e4E3b1DA2462752AeA980698c335E70E9AB26C"
,DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).sendAsync().get();
BigInteger nonce = txnCount.getTransactionCount();
System.out.println("Transaction Count "+ nonce);
```

Comment: 1. getting 0 tx count is totally legitimate count
2. Since you do have some tx in there, I think your code is constructed correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_gettransactioncount:

> Returns the number of transactions *sent* from an address.

The address `0xa9e4E3b1DA2462752AeA980698c335E70E9AB26C` has sent 0 transactions, so the correct result is, in fact, 0.